# CBCentralManager not detecting services from iPhone but works fine in iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, core-bluetooth

I'm able to connect to a BLE device through my app using CoreBluetooth framework. But when I read for services from BLE device, it never enters the delegate function,

```
func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: NSError?)
```

Although, this works fine in iPads. Is there some sort of configuration needed for it to make it work in iPhones?

This is how I call discoverServices inside didConnectPeripheral.

```
func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didConnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral) {

        print("inside didConnectPeripheral ...")
        print("Data : \(peripheral.identifier) : \(peripheral.description)")

        peripheral.delegate = self

        let customService:CBUUID = CBUUID(string: Constants.UUID.CustomServcices)
        peripheral.discoverServices([customService])
}
```

Note: Xcode v7.2, iPad OS: 8.1, iPhone OS: 8.1 and 9.1 (Tried both but doesn't detect services)
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What model iPhone are you using?

Comment: Does Bluelight find the services? I saw sometimes iOS totally hang about discovering the services, and a reboot of the iDevice and the BLE device was needed.

Comment: @Paulw11 I've tried this on iPhone 5s and iPhone 6 plus. Both don't work.

Comment: @Larme I haven't come across Bluelight? And yes, the iPhones I tried do get connected but don't discover the services at all. Reboot also doesn't help.

Comment: I think Larme meant the Light Blue app on the app store.  Can you show more code? How do you start service discovery?

Comment: @Larme I tried Light Blue app. It always times out after connecting. Doesn't show up the services.

Comment: You should edit your question to include the code rather than adding it as a comment

Comment: But make sure you save a reference to the connected peripheral in a property

Comment: @Paulw11 Sorry about that! I did try creating a strong reference to the peripheral. But no luck! :(

Comment: If LightBlue can't connect either then it sounds like an issue with your peripheral. I don't know why your iPad works though